# node.js - forward client to least loaded cluster

Tags: javascript, node.js, cluster-computing

I got nodejs application created with express. Application is divided into 4 clusters, where every cluster listen on a different port.
fe:

```
localhost:6001 for first cluster
localhost:6002 for second cluster
```

and so on..

 Can I somehow got a single address, where client ask server which one of clusters is least loaded from traffic and then forward it to this cluster? I'm mainly interested in forwarding client to a cluster port method of approach. 

If this is not possible, what is the right approach to achieve similiar behaviour ?

Comment: you shold try nginx upstream with hash load balancing

Answer (score 0):

If you need something like balancing and clusterisation from the box, you can try PM2: http://pm2.keymetrics.io/